# How do I display my html file on my page in Flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I'm trying to render my report to the page however the html code is showing not the actual object, how do I display the object.

```
profile = pp.ProfileReport(df, check_correlation=False)

return render_template('profile.html', my_bucket=my_bucket, profile=profile.to_html())
```

[image]

Comment: Edit the `profile.html` template to make sure that it says `{{ profile | safe }}`. That should render the profile inside the template.

Comment: Flask looks for HTML files in your ```templates``` folder on your machine.  So when you call render_template it checks there for your file. You may want to try ```profile.to_file()``` and write a file which you then refer to in ```render_tempalate``` as a work around if you cannot get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

adding `{{ profile | safe }}` to my code fixed the issue as it now renders the profile inside the template thanks @abdou